# Azure B2C mobile app in combination with a web api

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have setup a Azure B2C where I configured the B2C_1_sign_up_sign_in User flow. In addition I added an app registration where I added the Mobile and desktop applications platform. This is all working nicely and I can authenticate a mobile app. For this I receive an ID token. I want this mobile app to communicate with a C# web api. This web api should be able to validate the token. However I need an access token for this.

The api is configured like this:

```cs
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureB2C");
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(
        options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureB2C", options);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
        },
        options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureB2C", options);
        });
```

The AzureB2C have the following settings:

```
  "AzureB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[domain].onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "[clientId]",
    "TenantId": "[tenantId]"
  }
```

What would be the next step to take to get this scenario to work? How can I get an access token from within the mobile app that can be validated and used in the web api?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide access to the API for your client app. You'll then get an access token that can be used when making calls to the API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-api-application?tabs=app-reg-ga